# Well defined function in group theory

Tags: group-theory

Let G be a group and H be a subgroup.
(i) Show that ϕ:G/H→H∖G given by ϕ(gH)=Hg^{−1} is a well-defined function.

(ii) Likewise show that ψ:H∖G→G/H given by ψ(Hg)=g^{−1}H is a well-defined function.

Answer (score 1):

The map $\phi$ will be well defined when $aH=bH$ implies $\phi(aH)=\phi(bH)$, that is $Ha^{-1}=Hb^{-1}$.

For, let $x\in Ha^{–1}$ be. Hence $x=h_1a^{-1}$ for some $h_1\in H$, so
$x^{-1}=ah_1^{-1}$. Then $x^{-1}\in aH$.

Since $aH=bH$ then $x^{-1}\in bH$. This implies that $x^{-1}=bh_2$ for some $h_2\in H$. So $x=h_2^{-1}b^{-1}$ and $x\in Hb^{–1}$. Hence $Ha^{-1}\subseteq Hb^{-1}$.

With this in mind, perhaps you can complete the exercises.